# How to use a variable with setwd()?

Tags: r, variables, working-directory

Example:

```
var<-"name"
setwd("/media/data/var")
```

gives an error 'cause directory "/media/data/var" does not exist, but "/media/data/name".

So, how to declare var as variable within a quoted string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `paste`:

```
setwd(paste0("/media/data/",var))
```

Or you can use `file.path`:

```
setwd(file.path("/media/data",var))
```